# Unique identifiers for ui automation

Tags: angularjs, ui-automation

Our ui automation team is asking for a better way to select elements for their automated tests. My thinking is that we can inject a dedicated attribute (say "ui-auto") for each testable element. This attribute would have a value which is:

- unique
- persistent (doesn't change across sessions or page loads so as to not break the tests)
- predictable (follows some naming convention depending on action type, location, etc.)

My questions are:

1. Is this a good idea? better ideas are welcome.
2. Are there existing conventions for this?
3. What the best way to implement
   this?

I should mention that we are using angular and I thought that
    using some kind of directive and/or service would help automate
    this.

I should also say that I don't want to use the "id" attribute b/c I'd like to have separation between development concerns (ids may be used for javascript), and qa concerns (selection of elements for automated tests)

Comment: What's the test framework? protractor? You may not need an id but instead a particular attribute that doesn't change, such as a binding, ng-model, class hierarchy, etc. Otherwise I would add the id manually to be sure of what you do, it is not a bad idea per se especially if you decide a convention on such ids that indicate they are intented for tests only and should not be used by other JS code.

Comment: Thanks @floribon. The test framework is selenium (even though my recommendation was protractor :)

Comment: protractor uses selenium to automate the browser, but gives you a good angular framework to run jasmine tests, that's not incompatible and could save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Downvoter: perhaps care to explain the downvote, rather than just a quick downvote on someone with a low score.

Comment: @floribon - I agree with what you're saying about protractor, but this is not my decision ...

Comment: @PascalvKooten - Thank you. I do not mind a down vote, but an explanation would be nice, and a reference to an existing similar question (and answer) would be even better :)

Comment: agree with you guys, here's my upvote to balance

Answer (score 1):

In our implementation we add to the DOM element a data-awt attribute, the value consists of a context (page and mode) type and unique string.  As we use the EXTJS library our type is the xtype and the unique string is components name or text property.  The context is developer controlled by placing a unique property on the upper most parent and all children use this as their context.

In practice we end up with data-awt values like devicesListing-button-edit, deviceDetails-displayfield-name, deviceDetailsEditWindow-textfield-name.

We found that relying on css, id, or other attributes aren't reliable and predictable since we don't want to rewrite our tests whenever there is some UI change. Now the test only needs updating if an existing element changes its name (for example the PM says the name field should now use the 'customer' data from the DTO).

Comment: What about if there are several children of the same type under the parent ... how do you select them without ids? You could specify order, but that would def be vulnerable to UI changes.

Comment: @Xena in this case we added another property to the child items data-awt-postfix that is read at render time (remember using EXTJS) and appends that to the already formulated string, this is useful for lists of elements in things like radiogroups 

you end up with data-awt="context-type-radiogroup-radiooption" where radiooption is the data-awt-postfix the developer put on the child items in the radiogroup

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the class of the element and provide a unique identifier prefixed with something like "auto_" or "t_".

The agreement exists that if anyone changes the class name with that prefix, tests will break.

@o4ohel I agree that not using ids is better as devs also depend on them and they need to change sometimes. Identifiers for automation should be isolated. It's nice to have that separation.